# Como extraer el ultimo dato de una cadena

Tags: java, string, eclipse, substring

```
Quiero saber como puede extraer el último dato de una cadena
```

**Código**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numero="2 + 2 + 2 + 509 + 9";
        
        int ultimoPosicion=numero.length();
        
        System.out.println(numero.indexOf(ultimoPosicion));
    }
```

Con lo que tengo solo me saca la longitud de la cadena pero lo que quiero conseguir es que me saque el 9 por ejemplo o que si añado más números vaya saliendo el último que se ingrese.

Comment: podrias usar el metodo substring `System.out.println(numero.substring(ultimoPosicion-1,ultimoPosicion));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo más fácil sería hacerlo con arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numero = "2 + 2 + 2 + 509 + 944 + 9";
    String[] array = numero.split("");
    String ultimoPosicion = array[array.length - 1];
    System.out.println(ultimoPosicion);
}
```

**Output:**

```
// 9
```